# scanf format to ignore irrelevant characters

Tags: c, string-formatting, scanf

I wrote a short example code to illustrate my problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned parseAndCompareDouble(const char* inSTR, const char* inF, const char * expect, const char * outF){
    unsigned e = 0;
    char buffer[2000];
    double a = 0;
    if( 1 != sscanf_s( inSTR, inF, &a, sizeof(double) ) ) e += 1;
    if( (int) strlen(expect) != sprintf_s(buffer, 2000, outF, a) ) e += 1;
    if( 0 != strcmp(expect, buffer) ) e += 1;
    return e;
}

unsigned main( void )
{
    unsigned e = 0;
    const char * universalFormat = "X/%lf";

    e += parseAndCompareDouble("X/100", universalFormat, "X/100", "X/%3.0lf");
    e += parseAndCompareDouble("     X/100\r\n", universalFormat, "X/100", "X/%3.0lf");
    e += parseAndCompareDouble("     X/99\r\n", universalFormat, "X/99", "X/%2.0lf");
    e += parseAndCompareDouble("     X / 99 ", universalFormat, "X/99", "X/%2.0lf");
    e += parseAndCompareDouble("X/99", universalFormat, "X/99", "X/%2.0lf");
    e += parseAndCompareDouble("     \"X/100\"\r\n", universalFormat, "X/100", "X/%3.0lf");  

    if( 0 != e ){ printf( "%2u errors occured\n", e ); }
    else{ printf( "all pass\n", e ); }
    return e;
}
```

I am looking for a `universalFormat` that lets my example fixture pass the test. I tried to fiddle around with `%*s` but I just don't get it rigth. I am missing some concept.

Can someone provide the `universalFormat` that fits this example and explain how to get there.

Comment: I assume an "unnecessary" character is everything that's not in `expect`.  What about a function that creates a new string that removes all the unnecessary characters from `inStr`?  You would then call scanf on the new string.

Comment: @user2233706 your assumption is correct. I need to verify the content and read it multiple times. This will be part of a very limited math parser that needs to build and distinguish a known set of functiontypes. I will later rely on some characters to help me verify that i have the correct function. The functionformat is always whitespace + " + functiondata + " + whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following format:

```
const char * universalFormat = "%*[^/]/%lf";
```

The `%*[^/]` tells `scanf` to ignore everything that isn't a `/`. I am assuming your `sscanf_s` function will understand it, although I am unable to verify that myself. [Here's the working program (slightly modified).](http://ideone.com/wx2elw)

---

Daniel Fischer has brought to my attention that the `sscanf_s` and `sprintf_s` functions are defined in Annex K of C Standard 2011 (C11). [I raised a question about its relation to conformance.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16700541/315052)

---

> Knowing that `"X /"` is in the string is of importance for me.

It seems you are trying to use `sscanf` to parse free-form input, which is not really its *forte*. If you are willing to change your parsing code, you can use the modified version of the format string to accomplish this:

```
const char * universalFormat = "%[^/]/%lf";
```

Now, your parsing code will need to be updated to read in the string corresponding to the `%[^/]` specifier, and then you can do some simple scanning on it to make sure it meets your requirements.

```
char xbuffer[2000];
const char *xp;
/*...*/
if( 2 != sscanf_s( inSTR, inF, xbuffer, sizeof(xbuffer), &a, sizeof(a) ) ) e += 1;
if( (xp = strrchr(xbuffer, 'X')) == 0 || strcspn(xp, "X \t") != 0 ) e += 1;
```

Comment: Those seem to be the (optional) functions from Annex K of the standard. (glibc for example doesn't implement them [yet?], so they're not quite portable.) If they are, they understand the same formats as the `_s`-less versions.

Comment: +1 For your response, thx. I will try this tomorrow and accept afterwards. Knowing that '"X /"' is in the string is of importance for me. Also knowing that there is nothing else afterwards. I assume your answer will get me started here.

Comment: @user315052 validated :) - thx, the picture is a little bit clearer now.