# Is support of Annex K in C11 required for a conforming implementation?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, tr24731

While [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16697192/315052) that made use of some functions (`sscanf_s` and `sprintf_s`) that I thought were not standard C, Daniel Fischer brought to my attention that the functions in question were defined in Annex K.

I understand generally that *normative* means it helps define the standard. But, an annex to the C Standard has traditionally been treated as informative only. Annex K is labeled as normative in the C11 Standard. It defines "safe" functions.

*Does this mean a compiler that doesn't provided these functions does not conform to the C11 Standard?*

I only have the draft C11 Standard available to me, but it states that Annex K is normative, but the library section of the standard makes no mention of the functions discussed in Annex K. A note in the definition of *runtime-constraint* seems to imply Annex K defines an extension.

*Does a normative Annex only define an optional extension?*

Comment: Annexes D, F, G, K, L are all normative in ISO/IEC 9899:2011.  The others (A, B, C, E, H, I, J) are informative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Annex K is optional; it says so itself.

See K.2 paragraph 2:

> An implementation that defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` shall conform to the
> specifications in this annex.

with a footnote:

> Implementations that do not define `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` are not required to conform to these
> specifications.

And paragraph 3 says:

> Subclause K.3 should be read as if it were merged into the parallel
> structure of named subclauses of clause 7.

which is why it's not necessary to mention it in the library section, clause 7 (or at least the authors of the standard didn't feel it was necessary).

As of C11, an implementation that defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` must  define it as `201112L`; both N1570 and the released C11 standard got this wrong, but it was fixed in a Technical Corrigendum.

Comment: Thanks. I poked around the other normative annexes and see that all of them provide some macro to declare their availability, except for Annex D. Does this mean Annex D is required?

Comment: Yes, 6.4.2.1, which defines the syntax of identifiers, unconditionally refers to Annex D.

Answer (score 5):

It's "normative" in the sense that an implementation claiming to support Annex K must meet the requirements therein. It's not mandatory.

Comment: So a program that is written using features defined only in a conforming annex of the standard is not a strictly conforming program?

Comment: @user315052 "A strictly conforming program can use conditional features (see 6.10.8.3) provided the use is guarded by an appropriate conditional inclusion preprocessing directive using the related macro."

Comment: @DanielFischer: Gotcha, thanks. I figured that out after seeing Keith Thompson's answer.