# In Linux, do there exist functions similar to _clearfp() and _statusfp()?

Tags: linux, visual-c++, porting

Recently, I am doing a job about porting.
I encountered such a problem:
Some Windows API, such as _clearfp(), _statusfp() etc, then I can't find the corresponding functions in Linux.

So I am here to ask for help.

Comment: What do these functions do ? Please explain.

Comment: _clearfp():Gets and clears the floating-point status word.                _statusfp：Get the floating point status word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need a POSIX system, or a C99 compiler that supported Annex F of the C99 Standard. You can test if Annex F is supported by checking if the macro `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined. The relevant functions would be found in `<fenv.h>`.

```
int feclearexcept(int excepts); // clears exceptions (returns 0 on success)
int fetestexcept(int excepts);  // returns exceptions that are set
```

The exceptions passed in as `excepts`, and returned by `fetestexcept`, is a bitmask that can be test against the following macros:

```
FE_DIVBYZERO
FE_INEXACT
FE_INVALID
FE_OVERFLOW
FE_UNDERFLOW
FE_ALL_EXCEPT
```

The last macro, `FE_ALL_EXCEPT`, is just the bitwise-or of all the macros above it.

Comment: [`<fenv.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/fenv.h.html) is actually (also) POSIX, so should be portable across Unix systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you give me some use case about the functions?

Comment: @rubenvb: Well, it's POSIX since POSIX includes ISO C; recent POSIX versions include C99 and hence also fenv.h.

Comment: @janneb: I am basing the way I answer the question from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16700541/315052).

Comment: @jxh:I solved the problem with your method. Very thanks for your help.