# man pages for optional C11 Annex K functions

Tags: c, unix, c11, manpage, tr24731

As C11 introduced some new functions like

```
char *gets_s(char *str, rsize_t n);
```

how can I find these functions's man pages on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: you need to check to see if 12.04 supports a version of GCC that supports those functions first. Then worry about the man pages.

Comment: Yes, I have installed gcc 4.8 which should at least partially support C11 standard.

Comment: What man pages are you looking for? Most of the real changes in C11 are language feature and only a few functions are added or undergo changes. And for these the text of the standard should tell you enough of what they are doing, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is support of Annex K in C11 required for a conforming implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700541/is-support-of-annex-k-in-c11-required-for-a-conforming-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

You get the C11 Annex K functions, like this one, only with:

- safeclib-3.0 https://rurban.github.io/safeclib/doc/safec-3.0/d1/dae/md_doc_libc-overview.html
- MSVC (with some quirks)
- Embarcadero C++ libc